# Why is a part of CSS not taking effect when it is published?

Tags: html, css

Currently I use many .css files. Mostly for modals, or other pages. But most of my website is in 1 .css file.

So far it seems to be having no issue, but when published, the css won't go over some sections.

This is how it looks over locally: [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZnUe.png)

and here is how it looks when its published on the domain: [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJnJ9.png)

What i don't understand is why the CSS applies to the text above, but not at this one here.

This is the code for the buttons and CSS:

```
     <!--Linkedin-->
              <a type="button" href="" target="_blank" class="  btn-li"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in pr-1"></i> Linkedin</a>
              <!--Github-->
              <a type="button" class="  btn-git"><i class="fab fa-github pr-1"></i> Github</a>
              <!--Email-->
              <a type="button" class="  btn-email"><i class="fas fa-envelope pr-1"></i> Email</a>


/* Social Icons */
.btn-git{
    background-color: #1a1e23;
    color: white; 
    margin: 5px;

    border: none;

    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.btn-git:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: #363e47;

    border: none;

    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.btn-li{
    background-color: rgb(9, 111, 206);
    color: white; 
    margin: 5px;

    border: none;

    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.btn-li:hover{
    color: white    ;
    background-color: rgb(11, 131, 243);

}

.btn-email{
    background-color: #343536;
    color: white; 
    margin: 5px;

    border: none;

    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.btn-email:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: #626364;

}
```

maybe this is a .htaccess related issue? I have been getting issues left and right once I updated it.
This is the code for it tho:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jfif "access plus 1 month"


  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

This is how I import the css in:

Comment: @anonProxy Try adding your import statements again.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn’t it be cache related? Try new anonymous window of your browser.

Comment: nope, I always try in new brosers, new pc and even on phone